# Azure App Service swap takes over multiple times longer than a direct deploy

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have a very simple asp.net core hosted blazor wasm application on a S1 App Service with 2 slots: Integration and production. When I just publish into my integration slot that takes around 50 seconds. But when I swap the integration with the production slot it takes over 7 minutes. Both apps slots are after that very slow, often taking over a minute before they react again. During the swap both are not responding at all.

There are only 2 settings and the connection string to change. And I don't have any manual warmup.
Is the swap functionality just not really meant the be used on such a low configuration or can I adjust something in my configuration to speed things up?

Comment: Azure App Service swap may take longer than direct deploy due to factors like warm-up actions and resource availability. If swap operation is slow, check your App Service metrics. Custom warm-up actions can be specified using the applicationInitialization configuration element in web.config. Also, ensure app settings or connection strings are the same for both slots. Marking them as “Slot Settings” can help. I also skipped the swap logic and choose to do deploy only for production instead of swap.